# Unable to run deployed application on glassfish server

Tags: web-services, glassfish

I have successfully installed Glassfish on a Ubuntu 16.04 instance.
The deployment of my webservice is also succesfull, When I launch the application, I get a page that says

```
Web Application Links
If the server or listener is not running, the link may not work. In this event, check the status of the server instance. After launching the web application, use the browser's back button to return to this screen.
```

When I click on a link (both HTTP and HTTPS), I get a 404 error.
I presume that there must be something wrong with my server, but all tutorials about setting up a glassfish server seem to go straight out-of-the-box, so I don't get a clue why it isn't working in my case.
I also can't find where to check the listeners or server instance, and what they should be configured like.

Last thing to mention: I have never used glassfish before, I only need to test if a webservice is working like expected before sending it to a customer who will deploy it himself.

Comment: were you able to login to glassfish admin console?
https://yourhost:4848
username: admin
password: adminadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What directory structure do you use in your *.war file? By default static files (like index.html) should be placed in the root folder - not in the WEB-INF. So a typical directory structure would look like this:

```
myWebApp/
  WEB-INF/
    web.xml
    lib/
      MyLib.jar
    classes/
      mypackage/
        MyServlet.class
  index.html
  index.jsp
```

Comment: there was indeed an error in the project structure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I deploy a Web Service using REST and I have the same problem.
My structure is :

```
MyProject
    .idea
    lib
    out
    src
        MyApp
        Helloworld
    web
        web.xml
    WEB-INF
    index.jsp
    MyProject.iml
External Librairies
```

I followed a tuto (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service-on-glassfish-application-server.html#d76541e113) and I should have a web page on `http://localhost:port/appArtefact/helloworld`

Comment: If you have a question just use Ask Question